# Transfer file from Ubuntu computer to network drive

Tags: command-line, samba, ftp, transfer

I want to transfer a large file (1 GB size approx) from my computer with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to a Hard Drive connected to the USB port of my router. I want the transfer to be done automatically, thus it should be done via a script or the command line. The problem is that the file transfer takes 10-20h.

So far I have tried multiple options, like mounting the hard drive into my computer and then moving there the file, using the ftp protocol via the `ftp-upload` command and using the samba protocol via the `smbclient` command. All of them work but all are extremely slow.

I don't think it's neither a hardware nor an Internet limitation since I have a bandwidth of 30 Mb/s and all my downloads from the same computer are pretty fast. My router is the "Livebox Fibra" from the Orange company and its firmware is updated to the latest version.

Comment: 10 to 20 hours for 1 gig are you sure this is right? How long would it take to transfer a 1 GB file across a network operating at 100 Mbps?
on a Fast Ethernet connection (100 Mbps), it would take six minutes. on a Gigabit Ethernet connection (1 Gbps), it would take 36 seconds.   At 30 would be about 18 mins.

Comment: Plugging the hard drive into your computer and transferring 1Gb should take seconds. There is no faster solution.

Comment: Please update the question and explain what filesystems are used. If you transfer to NTFS... that will slow it down a lot. And yes this is a hardware limitation.  If the file is not zipped please do. If it has text the size will be 10% of the original file.  And I would use rsync for this. rsync has resume and a progress bar.